# Object to JSON conversion issue with jackson

Tags: java, json, object

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.report.mongo.MakeMD5Checksum;
import com.report.mongo.MongoService;

import job.com.rpt.bootstrap.ApplicationConfigCache;
import service.com.rpt.db.MongoDataService;
import service.com.rpt.util.RPTUtil;

public class DTOtoJSONTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Address studentAddress1 = new Address();
    studentAddress1.adrLine1 = "studentAddress1 adrLine1";
    studentAddress1.adrLine2 = "studentAddress1 adrLine2";
    studentAddress1.city = "studentAddress1 City";
    studentAddress1.postalCode = 1;

    Address studentAddress2 = new Address();
    studentAddress2.adrLine1 = "studentAddress2 adrLine1";
    studentAddress2.adrLine2 = "studentAddress2 adrLine2";
    studentAddress2.city = "studentAddress2 City";
    studentAddress2.postalCode = 2;

    StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO();
    studentDTO.name = "BK";
    studentDTO.roll = 1;
    studentDTO.age = 40;
    studentDTO.dateOfBirth = new Date();
    studentDTO.gender = "M";

    studentDTO.addresses = new Address[2];
    studentDTO.addresses[0] = studentAddress1;
    studentDTO.addresses[1] = studentAddress2;


    studentDTO.sportsInterests = new String[3];
    studentDTO.sportsInterests[0] = new String("Fooball");
    studentDTO.sportsInterests[1] = new String("VollyBall");
    studentDTO.sportsInterests[2] = new String("Carom");



    GurdianInfo father = new GurdianInfo();
    father.gurdianName = "Father Name";
    father.relation = "Father";
    father.address = new Address();
    father.address.adrLine1 = "Father addressline1";
    father.address.adrLine2 = "Father addressline2";
    father.address.city = "Father City";
    father.address.postalCode = 11;

    father.gurdianCntactInfo = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();

    ContactInfo fContactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    fContactInfo.isPrimary = true;
    fContactInfo.cellNumber = "1234";
    fContactInfo.emailId = "";
    fContactInfo.type = "Cell";

    father.gurdianCntactInfo.add(fContactInfo);

    fContactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    fContactInfo.isPrimary = false;
    fContactInfo.cellNumber = "5678";
    fContactInfo.emailId = "";
    fContactInfo.type = "Cell";

    father.gurdianCntactInfo.add(fContactInfo);

    fContactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    fContactInfo.isPrimary = false;
    fContactInfo.cellNumber = "";
    fContactInfo.emailId = "father email";
    fContactInfo.type = "email";

    father.gurdianCntactInfo.add(fContactInfo);

    studentDTO.gurdianInfo = new ArrayList<GurdianInfo>();
    studentDTO.gurdianInfo.add(father);


    GurdianInfo mother = new GurdianInfo();
    mother.gurdianName = "Father Name";
    mother.relation = "Father";
    mother.address = new Address();
    mother.address.adrLine1 = "Father addressline1";
    mother.address.adrLine2 = "Father addressline2";
    mother.address.city = "Father City";
    mother.address.postalCode = 11;

    mother.gurdianCntactInfo = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();

    ContactInfo mContactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    mContactInfo.isPrimary = true;
    mContactInfo.cellNumber = "PQRS";
    mContactInfo.emailId = "";
    mContactInfo.type = "Cell";

    mother.gurdianCntactInfo.add(mContactInfo);

    mContactInfo = new ContactInfo();
    mContactInfo.isPrimary = false;
    mContactInfo.cellNumber = "";
    mContactInfo.emailId = "mother email";
    mContactInfo.type = "email";

    mother.gurdianCntactInfo.add(mContactInfo);
    studentDTO.gurdianInfo.add(mother);

    CurriculamDetail curriculamDetail = new CurriculamDetail();
    curriculamDetail.curriculamName = "MCA";
    curriculamDetail.standard = "MASTERS";
    curriculamDetail.subjects = new String[3];
    curriculamDetail.subjects[0] = "SUB0";
    curriculamDetail.subjects[1] = "SUB1";
    curriculamDetail.subjects[2] = "SUB2";
    studentDTO.curriculamDetail = curriculamDetail;
    //Above part just creates an object
    // Main code starts below
    ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();

    mapperObj.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    JSONObject studentJSON = new JSONObject();
        convertToJSON(studentDTO, studentJSON);
        System.out.println(studentJSON.toJSONString()); //This line prints {}
    }


public static void convertToJSON(Object object, JSONObject jsonObject) throws Exception{

    ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
    mapperObj.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);

    String jsonStr = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(object); 
    ;
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject local = (JSONObject)parser.parse(jsonStr);
    jsonObject = local;
        mapperObj.writeValueAsString(object);
    System.out.println("AFTER CONEVRSION ****************** " + jsonObject.toJSONString());  //This line prints JSON 

}
```

}

In the above code I'm trying to covert an object to a JSON object using jackson. The object is getting converted to JSON Object, but the problem is the JSON object is available only in the convertToJSON method (it prints the JSON perfect). I'm not able to print the JSON in the main method. In main method, it prints "{}". Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You alter the reference of `jsonObject` in `convertToJSON` to a new object. `studentJson` stays the same empty object.

Comment: convertToJSON should **return** a JSONObject. Not take one as argument.